# Invalid Cast Exception on Membership GetUser method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am trying record user log in history. So I created a OnLoggedin event that records every time user successfully logged in. Here is my code:

```
protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 string userName = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login)(sender)).UserName.ToString(); ;
 MembershipUser CurrentUser = Membership.GetUser(userName); //Error Occurs here
```

I am getting "InvalidCastException" error. I checked the userName variable and it's fine, string value with the correct user name.

Any help would greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Your solution should work when looking to msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40w5063z(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. However, you can access **UserName** without casting to **Login** control.

```
string userName = Login1.UserName
```

***Note***: **Login1** is the ID of the **Login** control.